# SQL connection string in stimulsoft reports

Tags: wpf, connection-string, sql-server-express, stimulsoft

I have made my WPF project reports by stimulsoft reports with this SQL server connection string

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBNBO;Integrated Security=True;
```

I want to make a setup file for my project by Advanced Installer program for this purpose I have transferred my database to SQL express and I have moved MDF and LDF file to my debug project file. I need to change reports SQL connection string in stimulsoft reports so that it can execute correctly; but I don't know how to do this.
Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the SQL connection string, set during install time on your installer dialogs, into a config file then try to implement into your setup project similar settings like exposed in [Advanced Installer help file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-sql-save-string.html).